# how to give new message notification sound mute chat button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing one live chat application. There is one chat window where customer can chat with the operator. So there I implemented on notification sound on each upcoming and going message.

My problem is sound is coming properly but the problem is how to mute this sound if customer click mute chat button then it should disable until customer again click this button to play this sound.

Below is my method in jquery:

```js
var audio = new Audio('sound/y.mp3');
$('#' + ctrId).find('#divMessage').append(
    '<div class="msg_wrap">' +
    '<div class="avatar1"></div>' +
    '<div class="direct-chat-text"><span class="userName">:' +
    msg[i].userName + '</span> ' + '<span>' + msg[i].message +
    '</span>' + '</div>' + '</div>' +
    '<span style="margin-right: 30px;float:right;font-size: 11px;color: #8c8585;">' +
    msg[i].chatTime + '</span>'
).append(audio.play());
```

Comment: refer this fiddle http://jsbin.com/higor/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

Just put your code in an if-block. Assuming you have a checkbox with id "isMuted":

```
if($("#isMuted").is(':checked'))
{
 // do not play sound, maybe do something else, like flash the chat
}        
else
{
 // if not checked, play sound as you already do
var audio = new Audio('sound/y.mp3');
  $('#' + ctrId).find('#divMessage').append('<div class="msg_wrap">' + '<div class="avatar1"></div>' + '<div class="direct-chat-text"><span class="userName">:' + msg[i].userName + '</span> ' + '<span>' + msg[i].message + '</span>' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '<span style="margin-right: 30px;float:right;font-size: 11px;color: #8c8585;">' + msg[i].chatTime + '</span>').append(audio.play());
 }
```